# yii2 chang YII:$app->user to Yii::$app->admin?

Tags: php, yii2

I have tried

```
'admin' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\User',
    'identityClass' => 'app\models\AdminIdentity',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
],
```

but there is an error:

```
Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException

User::identityClass must be set.
```

not working ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this error come from user user component configuration, not from your admin component configuration. Maybe in your user component configuration, you forgot to configure identityClass.
Try this user configuration :

```
'components' =>  [
  ...
  'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'app\models\User', //<= this
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
  ],
  ...
]
```